# What does O/C stand for?

Tags: legal-terms

The abbreviation or notation O/C appears in many references to legal proceedings in Georgia, such as: "O/C Theft by Taking" and "O/C Driving While License Suspended". What does O/C stand for or mean?
(Source https://sowegalive.com/2019/04/01/bainbridge-and-decatur-county-arrest-reports-4-1-19/)

Comment: Given that it always appears in constructions like "probation violation O/C ..." or "failure to appear O/C ..." , I strongly suspect that it means something like "original charge".  In other words, Mr. Barrett (in the first entry) was at some point convicted of theft by taking, had probation as part or all of his sentence, and violated the terms of his probation.  But this is just a guess on my part, which is why it's only a comment rather than a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Original charge."

It's the charge that had someone in court to begin with, and eventually leading to the new charge listed.

Comment: Can you offer a source?

Comment: Practical experience.